# How to get HTML of external website using server-side javascript

Tags: xpages

I want to get the HTML code / data of any website by using server-side javascript. How can I achieve this?

PS: I need this because from client-side javascript i can't do XMLHttpRequest of external domains due to the same origin policy.

Comment: When you say server-side javascript do you mean node.js?

Comment: What about JSONP? See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/io/script.html#dojo-io-script

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but to my mind the people controlling the remote data have to provide it in JSONP format in order for this to work. Hence I cannot get the HTML code of ANY site.

Comment: Yes, this cannot be used for every website. It was just an idea because your question looked like that it is going in this direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Quick-n-Dirty solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:label id="labelURL">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var url:java.net.URL = new java.net.URL("http://google.com");
            url.openConnection();
            var is:java.io.InputStream = url.openStream();
            var c;
            var result = "";
            while( (c = is.read()) != (-1) ){
                result += @Char(c);
            }
            is.close();
            result
        }]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:label>
</xp:view>
```

A better solution accessing remote urls is to use http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: Thanks very much, that was exactly the "quick-n-dirty" solution that I was looking for. Just perfect!

Comment: I got this exception: HTTP JVM: java.lang.SecurityException: not allowed to make a socket connection to google.com,80 . Do you know what configuration needs to be changed to get it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

A little less Q&D way is [described here](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8BQNWN). It uses, as Sven suggested, the Apache HTTP client which provides authentication, automatic redirects etc.